# .NETFramework,Version=v4.5 framework is a higher version than the currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v3.5"

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-3.5, .net-4.5

I created my first project in Framework 3.5 and i converted to framework 4.5 and its working perfectly. Secondly i tried to add the reference of this project to another project which is created in framework 4.5. while building my second project after adding the reference i am getting an error message:

```
1. The primary reference "xxx" could not be resolved because it was built against the ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" framework. This is a higher version than the currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v3.5".
2. The type or namespace name 'xxx' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

pls advice where i am missing something

Comment: What you're seeing at Project Properties / Application / Target Framework of the converted (current) project?

Comment: Wrong .NET Framework version. Double check.

Comment: Also ensure you're refering to the newly built assembly

Comment: Its a perfect help.. Thanks.. I missed to change the framework version here :  Project Properties / Application / Target Framework

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your second project is not targeting the .net 4.5 framework. You can right click your second project and go to properties ->Application.

It will say target framework is 3.5, change that to 4.5 and make sure this is also the case for your first project as well